# Four trip discount on Netherlands trains?

Tags: trains, budget, netherlands, amsterdam

AMS to Amsterdam, next day to Haarlem and back, third day back to Schiphol.

Each single trip is €4 but is there a way to combine them into less than €16?

Also, for the Haarlem trip, I’ll have a bicycle.  I understand that normally adds €6—does it affect the discount (if such exists)?

Comment: Only if you have chip card and travel with someone who has 40% discount

Comment: A cheaper way to travel might be by bus, but you can not take your bike in a bus. Or just travel by bike.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In the Netherlands, there are different rail cards, some group discounts and special offers but no discount for multiple/return travel.

A day return costs exactly the same as a single. Except for international trains like Thalys, available fare do not change over time and reserving a specific seat is not possible so absolutely no reason not to buy single tickets at the last minute if you want to.

Comment: ¡Gracias!  (Haven’t learned Dutch yet)

Comment: `Bedankt` is very common ;)

I have to correct @Relaxed though: the old-school disposable ticket has recently been replaced with disposable RFID cards (at almost every station), which costs EUR 1. So travelling with your own RFID card is actually cheaper.

Comment: @JaagHaagmans I didn't know that (I thought the disposable RFID cards would still cost the same) but it's still isn't cheaper to get a regular chip card for a visitor contemplating only a few journeys. You need to pay EUR 7.5 and then have to deal with the annoying credit business so that you end up with a lot of money tied into the card.

Comment: If you have to buy it and aren't planning on taking any trams, buses or the metro, it's more expensive of course. If you do, it gets cheaper very fast. However, it's quite common for departing tourists to donate their card at Schiphol airport to arriving tourists, just like it's common in The Netherlands to give your 1-day parking ticket to an arriving driver when you leave. More often than not, you'll also find some remaining credit on the card, because it costs money to get it back.

Answer (score 0):

TL;DR: Yes for the question in the title, but no for the specifics in the body.

There *are* four trip discounts in the Netherlands. Or rather, you can travel with four people for a fixed price. However, that's only interesting for longer trips than between Haarlem and Amsterdam (which are very close together). For longer trips though, it certainly pays. The [Groupticket off-peak hours](https://www.ns.nl/producten/en/meest-gekocht/p/groepsticket-daluren) always you to travel (one-way) with four people for € 30. To expensive to use it to travel to Haarlem, but I wanted to mention this anyway, in case someone is triggered by your question and checks it out.